# Custom domains and subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, cname, amazon-route53

We have an application that assigns our customers their own individual subdomains as their user accounts. We now want to also allow our customers to use their own custom subdomains or domains to show data that is loaded from our server, a la Tumblr or Wordpress.

Is there a way to programmatically use Amazon's AWS (perhaps Route 53) to make this possible (maybe by mapping their assigned subdomains on our server with their custom domain?).

I am so new to this and any guidance would be very helpful. At the minimum, can someone describe how Tumblr and/or Wordpress actually allow users to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Friend domain names are assigned to ip adress using dns service of the registrar site.
Generally we are provided with two domains .
Take the case of Wapka
you are provided with two domains ns1.wapka.mobi
ns2.wapka.mobi
It is how it is done 
 a demo.
http://wap.wapka.com/wap/en/help/typeId/135/typeName/Own+domain-+take+.tk+for+example
But its different in case of Blogspot.

Comment: Not sure I even understand. Could you please explain this a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard in domain names/Route 53. For example, you can point *.yoursite.com to your server (A record or CNAME). sub1.yoursite.com will now point to your domain and so will sub2.yoursite.com. If you are using Wordpress, accessing nonexisting.yoursite.com will trigger a new site generation. You can use http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/ to map custom domains in Wordpress. All they will have to do is create theirsite.yoursite.com then point their domain name to theirsite.yoursite.com and then change the settings in WP plugin.